# Can ngAnimate be used without defining CSS3 classes or JavaScript?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Is it possible to use [ngAnimate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3angAnimate) without any CSS3 or JavaScript? Let's say if you simply need to toggle the opacity, can you just do it in the markup?

```
<div ng-show='foo == 'yes'' ng-animate="show: 'opacity:1', hide: 'opacity:0'" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animation in the browser either needs to happen by (1) letting the browser's rendering engine handle it via CSS, or (2) controlling it yourself with JavaScript. So, somewhere, one of these two things needs to happen.

That said, you could build your own directive that *builds* the correct CSS and/or JavaScript on the fly and attaches/applies it to the given element, but I believe that using `ngAnimate` as provided is probably easier.

An example for those coming into `ngAnimate` for the first time:

HTML:

```html
<div ng-show="foo == 'yes'" ng-animate="{show: 'fade'}"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
.enter-fade {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  -moz-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  -o-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  transition: 1s linear opacity;

  opacity: 0;
}

.enter-fade.enter-fade-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Or, if you're supporting browsers that don't support CSS3 transitions, you can do the transition with JavaScript instead:

```javascript
myModule.animation('fade', function() {
  return { 
    setup : function(element) {
      element.css({'opacity': 0}); 
    },
    start : function(element, done, memo) {
      element.animate({'opacity': 1}, function() {
        done(); 
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can find more information at these great Yearofmoo articles:

- [Animation in AngularJS](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html)
- [Enhanced Animation in AngularJS](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/05/enhanced-animations-in-angularjs.html)

Comment: wouldn't be cool though if angular team adds that in future release? Most of the time you need simple stuff like jquery's `$.fadeIn()`,`$.fadeOut()`,`$.fadeToggle()` etc.

Comment: I don't think so, personally. The CSS (or JavaScript) listed above is enough to make a *completely reusable* transition, and it's only 8-10 lines of code. It would also be quite easy to build a third-party module that created animation CSS and/or JS on the fly (as mentioned) so that you wouldn't have to write anything yourself. That said, if you really did want to be able to write that kind of HTML to get the result you want, a custom directive would be the way to go and, I believe, not that difficult. I will make some time today to give that a shot and post the results here.

Comment: jquery functions I mentioned can do it with only 1 line of code. Although if we could do that declaratively on the markup, that would be great.

Comment: They CSS naming requirements have changed. Please update this post to include them. You can find out more here: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/05/enhanced-animations-in-angularjs.html